# Visual Studio IDE issues with clicking/selecting items

Tags: visual-studio

I'm having issues with my Visual Studio where, when I try to click on or select something, my cursor seems to be clicking on or selecting something else. It's like Visual Studio is interpreting my cursor to be somewhere else within the IDE.

Examples:
I'm trying to scroll but any click on the scroll bar is opening up the Error List panel at the bottom and randomly clicking on warnings and errors. If I try to click on the right side of the scroll bar, random files are selected and opened from Solution Explorer.

This also frequently occurs when I try to search (Control F) and clicking in the search bar will select files in the Solution Explorer.

Information:
I have Visual Studio open in a second monitor that is larger than my first. If I move Visual Studio back to the first, the problem is fixed, so I'm thinking it has something to do with resolution issues moving from one monitor to the next. I'd like to keep VS in my second monitor because it provides more room to look at code.

I've tried researching this issue and just haven't been able to find anyone with similar experiences. Does anyone know why this could be happening and what I can do to solve it?

Edit: Forgot important information about versions and OS. I'm on Windows 10 running VS Enterprise 2019. In the Display Settings, I have 'Extend these Displays' with the recommended resolutions.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with Windows 10 (build 19043.1110) and VS2019 Community (up-to-date). I have two displays connected to an Nvidia GTX 1060 (up-to-date driver), with the main display at 1920x1080 through DisplayPort and the second display at 3960x2160 through HDMI. I tried with 200% and 100% scaling on the second display. How do you have your displays connected?

Comment: @Andrew I appreciate you looking into it. I have a monitor connected to a Dell Laptop via HDMI. First display (laptop) is at 1920X1080  at 150% scaling and second also at 1920 X 1080 at 100@ scaling.

Comment: Does Dell Update have anything to offer?

Comment: I'm having this exact issue and it was driving me crazy. Also a Dell laptop using HDMI. The resolution on my second monitor is less than on my laptop though. I just switched to Display Port and that fixes the issue immediately (also then I can run a higher resolution on the second monitor). Did you manage to find other solutions?

Comment: Hey Ben, thanks for the response. I'll look into a Display Port in the future. I did find a solution but I left that position and don't have that Dell laptop anymore, so unfortunately I can't look into what setting I changed. It was not a perfect solution though.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue , it happened when I extended my display to a second monitor. I changed the scaling from 100% to 150% and kept the resolution as 1920*1080 in the second monitor. I just changed it and I checked the problem solved . I will continue checking to see how it goes , I will update the post if it didn`t work, but so far so good

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and managed to fix it using this workaround:

1. Go to **Tools** > **Options** > **Environment/General**
2. Uncheck **Optimize rendering for screens with different pixel densities**
3. Restart Visual Studio